# Data binding or Observables which to use?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Recently i started to working in a new angular project. In that project developers heavily uses observables. I am new to this approach.

Normally i write code

```
<div *ngIf="showBlock">
....code here
</div>
```

in ts

```
determineView(){
  this.showBlock = true;
}
```

In the new project

```
<div *ngIf="showBlock | async">
....code here
</div>
```

in ts

```
 determineView(){
  this.showBlock.next(true);
}
```

So which is good practice for performance in a big project with lots of bindings ?

Comment: If the condition value is not coming from an I/O source or stream then there is no reason to use observables. Example: If the value is coming from a network call then observable makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Main advantage behind using an observable is while dealing with Network/API calls where data coming is quite large also to handle HTTP Requests corresponding status and error codes etc.

While Data binding allows you to connect the data from your application with the UI. The data-binding syntax lowers the amount of manual coding.